# Fuzzing the Linux Kernel: A student in peril.

Tags: linux, security, linux-kernel, kernel, fuzzing

I am currently a student at a university studying a computing related degree and my current project is focusing on finding vulnerabilities in the Linux kernel. My aim is to both statically audit as well as 'fuzz' the kernel (targeting version 3.0) in an attempt to find a vulnerability.

My first question is 'simple' is fuzzing the Linux kernel possible? I have heard of people fuzzing plenty of protocols etc. but never much about kernel modules. I also understand that on a Linux system everything can be seen as a file and as such surely input to the kernel modules should be possible via that interface shouldn't it?

My second question is: which fuzzer would you suggest? As previously stated lots of fuzzers exist that fuzz protocols however I don't see many of these being useful when attacking a kernel module. Obviously there are frameworks such as the Peach fuzzer which allows you to 'create' your own fuzzer from the ground up and are supposedly excellent however I have tried repeatedly to install Peach to no avail and I'm finding it difficult to believe it is suitable given the difficulty I've already experienced just installing it (if anyone knows of any decent installation tutorials please let me know :P).

I would appreciate any information you are able to provide me with this problem. Given the breadth of the topic I have chosen, any idea of a direction is always greatly appreciated. Equally, I would like to ask people to refrain from telling me to start elsewhere. I do understand the size of the task at hand however I will still attempt it regardless (I'm a blue-sky thinker :P A.K.A stubborn as an Ox)

Cheers

A.Smith

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think a good starting point would be to extend Dave Jones's Linux kernel fuzzer, Trinity: http://codemonkey.org.uk/2010/12/15/system-call-fuzzing-continued/ and http://codemonkey.org.uk/2010/11/09/system-call-abuse/

Dave seems to find more bugs whenever he extends that a bit more.  The basic idea is to look at the system calls you are fuzzing, and rather than passing in totally random junk, make your fuzzer choose random junk that will at least pass the basic sanity checks in the actual system call code.  In other words, you use the kernel source to let your fuzzer get further into the system calls than totally random input would usually go.

Comment: Just looked at the links you posted. Seems like a good source of information on kernel module fuzzing as well as a nice open source project. Thanks for the info. A good step in the right direction. Have you used this tool yourself? Can you vouch for its stability, reliability, etc.?

Comment: No, I haven't used it, but I know that Dave has found a number of kernel bugs with it.  The whole point of a fuzzer is that it's supposed to be unstable and crash your whole system :)

Comment: Fair enough. But I have heard of fuzzers which will be left for a while and just fall over and not record any crashes. A friend of mine experienced this with the Sulley framework not long ago. None the less I will definitely be checking the project out. Thanks for the input :)

Answer (score 4):

"Fuzzing" the kernel is quite a broad way to describe your goals.
From a kernel point of view you can

- try to fuzz the system calls
- the character- and block-devices in /dev

Not sure what you want to achieve.

Fuzzing the system calls would mean checking out every Linux system call (http://linux.die.net/man/2/syscalls) and try if you can disturb regular work by odd parameter values.

Fuzzing character- or block-drivers would mean trying to send data via the /dev-interfaces in a way which would end up in odd result.

Also you have to differentiate between attempts by an unprivileged user and by root.

My suggestion is narrowing down your attempts to a subset of your proposition. It's just too damn broad.

Good luck -
Alex.

Comment: My appologies. I can indeed see that the question was extremely broad despite my intentions of narrowing it. If I'm honest I should add another question to my list: where do I target the kernel? The reason for the breadth of my question is because I'm unsure where to actually start fuzzing. Can you suggest a decent starting point?

Comment: Look for something which is ubiquitous but not very well researched. For instance... I don't know, like a driver for a Wifi card. I got me a Realtek Wifi-adaptor with a really crappy driver and userspace configuration programm. The userspace program directly interfaces with the hardware and is made of coprolithic matter. The userspace program has so many rights (suid root) but yet is so crappy that it does everthing but setting the WPA2 key correctly. I'd start fuzzing the hell out of one of those things - in userspace - and see how far you get.

Comment: Yeah that seems like very good advice. Thank you very much for your response. I'm intending to start looking  further into potential targets this week. I will update this post if I find my 'ideal' target.

Answer (score 1):

One way to fuzzing is via system call fuzzing.

Essentially the idea is to take the system call, fuzz the input over the entire range of possible values - whether it remain within the specification defined for the system call does not matter.